# How to get row data if i use event selectionChanged on checkbox

Tags: angular, ag-grid

I use ag-grid on own aplication. I use option  checkboxSelection: true.When i click on checkbox event selectionChanged do not consist form data of row.How to get this data?

code

```
<ag-grid-common #agGridComponent 
    [gridName]="gridName" 
    [rowData]="supersessionParts" 
    [columnDefinitions]="columnDefs"
    [nodeChildDetails]="getNodeChildDetails" 
    (selectionChanged)="selectionChanged($event)">
</ag-grid-common>
```

code for set checkbox

```
{
      headerName: 'Cart',
      lexid: 4456,
      colId: 'selectColumnAdvanced',
      field: 'group',
      checkboxSelection: true,
      suppressResize: true,
      suppressMovable: true,
      suppressSorting: true,
      minWidth: 30,
      width: 35,
      headerComponentFramework: <{new(): CartHeaderComponent}>CartHeaderComponent
}
```

Comment: Please add more information. You could provide some code so we can help you better. Please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 2):

The `(selectionChanged)` callback has the parameter of type `SelectionChangedEvent` which contains the grid api. From the api, you can get the selected row(s). So your `selectionChanged` should look like:

```
onSelectionChanged(event: SelectionChangedEvent) {
    console.log(event.api.getSelectedRows());
}
```

This is way to go as specified in the ag-grid documentation (see [here](https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-events/)).

Comment: How to get that particular row data?

Comment: @aswininayak you can use the `rowClicked` event. Take a look at [this](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ag-grid-angular-hkr2c8) Stackblitz.

Comment: No good at all. Row data should be available as a property on SelectionChangedEvent, as there are circumstances where you'll need to get the clicked row data while doing something with the selected rows.